# Beresheet 5:24 - What happened to Enokh?

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar, genesis-bereishith

In this genealogical chapter, in the portion enumerating the lineage from *Metushelakh* to *Noakh*, everyone gets an "and he died" except for *Enokh*, who gets an "and he was no longer, for God had taken him." I thought I recalled this as the basis of a *midrash* that says that Enokh ascended to heaven alive and became a member of the *malahkhay hamlakhem*. Anyone know where this might be found textually?

https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8169/jewish/Chapter-5.htm

Comment: The apocryphal books of Enoch, from the Second Temple period are the earliest sources for this material. Fragments of the original Aramaic have been recovered at Qumran. However, ancient translations of the entire text exist to this day.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to arriving in heaven alive look at the [Sefer HaYashar, Bereishis 14](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.5.24?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sefer_HaYashar_(midrash)%2C_Book_of_Genesis%2C_Bereshit.14&lang2=bi) which writes:

> And on the seventh day a great storm arose and Enoch was carried heavenwards in a fiery ‎chariot, drawn by fiery horses.‎ And on the seventh day, all the kings that were with Enoch, sent to ascertain the number of ‎men that remained and followed Enoch to the place whence he ascended into heaven.‎ And when the messengers came to the place, they found it full of snow and large blocks of ice ‎all around.‎ And they said to each other: Let us break asunder these blocks of ice and see whether the ‎men going with Enoch did not die under them.‎ And they searched for all of them but Enoch was not found, for he had gone up into heaven.‎ And all the days of Enoch that he lived upon the earth were three hundred and sixty-five ‎years; and it was in the one hundred and thirteenth year of the life of Lamech, the son of ‎Methuselah, that Enoch was translated into heaven.‎ And after Enoch had departed from the earth all the kings of the earth assembled and ‎anointed Methuselah king over them, in the place of his sire."....(Sefaria translation)

And refer to the [Midrash Aggada](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.5.24?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Midrash_Aggadah%2C_Genesis.5.24.1&lang2=bi) for him enjoying the company of the malachim:

> ויתהלך חנוך את האלהים. עם המלאכים הלך שלש מאות שנה בגן עדן היה עמם ולמד מהם עיבור ותקופות ומזלות וחכמות רבות:
>
> Enoch walked with G-d: He went with the angels, for 300 years he was with them in Gan Eden and he learnt from them calculations of time, the constellation and many types of wisdom.